# Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded using react Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation-v5

I have a login screen which I have placed in stack. After user logs in successfully he is redirected to home screen which is a drawer screen. One of the options of drawer screen is logout, so on click of it user should be logged out. Following is my code for logout screen. I am just showing a progress bar in logout screen in ui but in `useEffect` hook, I am calling the following code

```
navigation.reset({
   routes: [{name: LOGIN_SCREEN}],
});
```

I also tried calling the above method in `useLayoutEffect` but then the logout button just hangs.

My Navigation stack looks something as follows

```
<Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name={LOGIN_SCREEN}
      component={LoginScreen}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name={HOME_STACK_SCREEN}
      component={DrawerStack}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />

    // ...

</Stack.Navigator>
```

My drawer component as follows

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerStyle={{backgroundColor: BLUE_COLOR_1}}
  drawerContentOptions={{labelStyle: {color: '#FFF'}}}
>
    <Drawer.Screen
      name={HOME_SCREEN}
      component={Home}
      options={{
        // ...
      }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name={LOGOUT_SCREEN}
      component={Logout}
      options={{
       // ...
      }}
    />

    // ...

</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Following is my logout component

```
const Logout = ({navigation}) => {
    async function logout() {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.clear();
            navigation.reset({
                index: 0,
                routes: [{name: LOGIN_SCREEN}],
            });
        } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert(e.toString());
            console.log(e.toString());
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
         logout();
    }, []);

    return <ProgressBar />;
};
```

Comment: can you share `Logout` component?

Comment: Why do you want Logout component? Just use drawerContent to render a custom one with logout and do the reset.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal but how to do with React Navigationv5. All the solutions online show how to do it with v4 or previous. I cant find anything related to docs about this in v5

Comment: @koox00 i have added the code in wuestion. please check

Answer (score 0):

`Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded using react Navigation v5` occurs when something going in an infinite loop

```
navigation.reset({
    routes: [{name: LOGIN_SCREEN}],
});
```

When you say you put the above code in `useEffect`, I suspect that hook is getting called multiple times.

Comment: but I have put empty array in my useEffect which calls it only once useEffect(()=>{navigation.reset({
        routes: [{name: LOGIN_SCREEN}],
      });},[])

Comment: Have you put this effect in Login_screen itself?

Comment: I have put this in logout screen. why would I put it in login? @maulikdhameliya

Answer (score -1):

I saw you code, to be honest it does't look good to me if we think of auth flow, Here are reason why I am saying this. Do check this link step by step , you get to know how simply you can achieve this auth flow in proper manner. [React Navigation Auth Flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow), this problem comes when we try to navigate screen from android back button , `user can go back to login after you navigate user to home page on success login`

**Second you can try one condition in you current code.**

You need to check one condition before calling the logout function in you screen

```
useEffect(()=>{
 if(check if user value if still there in async storage ) {
 **Here you can excute you code for log out **
 }
}
```

And instead of using reset action from navigation use **popToTop** , Here you can find the ref how you can us [PopToTop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions#poptotop) or use this

```
navigation.popToTop()
```

**Cheers !!**